# Angular Typscript select bind choose and change

Tags: angular, typescript

If I need two select lab
one select: Iced drink , Hot drink
If I choose ice drink, the Two select will appear Black tea, green tea, coffee
If I choose Hot drink, the Two select will appear Milk,Chocolate milk
How to change the items that can be selected in the second option because of the difference in the first option?

Now my code:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Select Table</mat-label>
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectshowedOption" (ngModelChange)="getselectedtableOption($event)" name="type">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let table of options" [value]="table.name">
                {{table.name}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>


options = [
    { name: "ICE Drink", value: 1 },
    { name: "HOT Drink", value: 2 }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way if just create two "seconds" select and use

```
<mat-select *ngIf="selectshowedOption==1" [(ngModel)]="drink">
   ...
</mat-select> 
<mat-select *ngIf="selectshowedOption==2" [(ngModel)]="drink">
   ...
</mat-select>
```

Another one is declare a new variable

```
hotDrinks=[....]
coldDrinks=[....]
secondTable:any=this.hotDrinks //a new variable
```

Then you iterate over `secondTable` and in your select change the "secondTable" variable

```
<mat-select [ngModel]="selectshowedOption" 
            (ngModelChange)="selectshowedOption=$event;
                             secondTable=$event==1?hotDrinks:coolDrinks">
...
</mat-select>
```